# Insert bitmap image in Excel file(xlwt) in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xlwt

I need to insert an Bitmap image in Excel file(creating using xlwt). i tried to insert using insert_bimap() method but it return IO Error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__    
   handler.get(*groups)  
File "C:\apps\test.py", line 44, in get
ws0.insert_bitmap('images/logo.gif', 2, 2)
File "C:\apps\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1034, in insert_bitmap
bmp = Bitmap.ImDataBmpRecord(filename)
File "C:\apps\xlwt\Bitmap.py", line 255, in __init__
self.width, self.height, self.size, data = _process_bitmap(filename)
File "C:\apps\xlwt\Bitmap.py", line 195, in _process_bitmap
fh = file(bitmap, "rb")
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 578, in __init__
raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'images/logo.gif'
```

Code:

```
  class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):        
     def get(self):
        wb = Workbook()
        ws0 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')
        ws0.write(0, 2, "chg wid: none")
        ws0.insert_bitmap('images/logo.gif', 2, 2)

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/ms-excel'
        self.response.headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'Binary'
        self.response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Sample.xls"'
        wb.save(self.response.out)
```

Please let me know if Any Workaround for this ?

Cheers! ,
NN

Comment: Have you tried reading 'images/logo.gif' using any other method (such as opening it directly)?  Permission denied doesn't sound like an xlwt problem, it sounds like you don't have access to the file.  It could be that `insert_bitmap` is trying to open the file for writing, but that's not what the traceback `rb` says.

Comment: yes. i can access it by http://localhost:8081/images/logo.gif .

Comment: I didn't mean through a web browser, I meant can your MainHandler routine access the file?  Instead of creating a workbook, just open the logo.gif file and read the first byte.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `insert_bitmap()` works only with bmp format. Open your gif file, save a copy under bmp format and call it with `insert_bitmap('images/logo.bmp',2,2)`, it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this project is long since done, but check out xlsxwriter

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_images.html

It's a lot better at inserting images than xlwt, supports jpegs and png files, not just bmp

> if you need to offset -and- scale an image in one insert:
>
> > worksheet.insert_image('B5', '/python/reports/garmentspreadsheet/Images/Garments/6702RD-WH.jpg', {'x_offset': 2, 'y_offset': 2, 'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})

offsets are in pixels

Don't have xlsxwriter

- pip install xlsxwriter

don't have pip? it's like easy_install

- centos/redhat

  yum install python-pip
  or
  yum install pip
- debian

  apt-get install pip

Comment: Big note on this answer: xlsxwriter can not read excel sheets only produce new ones. So if you want to insert an image into an existing one xlsxwriter is not the right tool.

Comment: You can read xlsx data using openpyxl and numpy or others http://www.python-excel.org/  and then use xlsxwriter to make a new xlsx file with the new data / images added and merged wherever. Often I've found making a new file works better then altering and xlsxwriter is best for images. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371163/reading-xlsx-files-using-python