# Insert PDF into Excel, Python

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I wrote a python script that I use to create a spreasheet with various calculations. I want to further insert a pdf into the spreadhseet (pdf is desireable, but a jpeg is useable). I've been flipping through xlwt and can't find anything. Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this?

Comment: PDF won't be possible because it's not a format that Excel understands natively. A quick search shows that xlwt can insert .bmp files only with `insert_bitmap`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741694/insert-bitmap-image-in-excel-filexlwt-in-gae

Comment: So fire up MS Paint and get to work!

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Excel 2007 and if you choose the Insert tab and choose the 'Object' button, you can add in a pdf without any issues. 'Adobe Acrobat Document' is a valid object type. I saw the insert_bmp function, but I can't use a bitmap for other reasons.

Comment: I'm not a python guy so I can't tell you whether xlwt supports this, but what you need to do is add an OLEObject to the Worksheet's `Shapes` collection. In Excel VBA this is simply `sht.Shapes.AddOLEObject Filename:="C:\filename.pdf", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually insert a PDF, you may need to just use Excel.  The most convenient way to automate a running instance of Excel is probably VBA or VBScript, but you can still use Python with [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) or [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/).

If it's important to stick with Python and it's acceptable to generate `.xlsx` instead of `.xls`, your best bet is [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter), which lets you import JPEG or PNG (in addition to BMP).  Here's [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/worksheet.html#insert_image) and an [example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_images.html#ex-insert-image) for inserting images with XlsxWriter.