# Insert an object to excel by using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to add some object to my excel sheet,
I'm using openpyxl, 
In excel you do it by:
Insert->Object

Is there a way to do it thru openpyxl or any other excel tool that working with python?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16408347/4044988](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16408347/4044988) have a look on this answer. I hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

While this is not currently possible with openpyxl I suspect it would be fairly straightforward to add the relevant functionality using the `add_image()` method as a starting place.

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

picture = openpyxl.drawing.Image('/path/to/picture')
picture.anchor(ws.cell('cell to put the image'))
ws.add_image(picture)

wb.save('whatever you want to save the workbook as')
```

This code of course refers to creating a new workbook and adding the image into it. To add the image to your preexisting workbook you would obviously just load that workbook using `load_workbook`.

Comment: I don't want to add image, I would like to add some "pdf" or "word" file